# Why is OLS valid for the AR process?

Tags: statistics, time-series

Is it valid to apply OLS to the AR process?
I learn that there exist correlation between explanatory variables and error term in AR model. I'm wondering how can show that $$E(u_t|x_t)\ne0$$,where vector of explanatory variable $x_t=(1, y_1,y_2,...,y_{t-1})$

And if AR model can not satisfy the assumption of BLUE, why OLS still used to estimate coefficient of AR model?

Statistical proof would be greatly appreciated, and if not, an intuition would be enough.

Remind that I'm looking for insights, not all the right answers.

Comment: I need more details on what you mean by "can't be applied/not valid", because on searching this up I found [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/240383/why-is-ols-estimator-of-ar1-coefficient-biased) where users claim that one can use OLS to find coefficients of AR(1) but the resulting estimator is biased (although it is consistent).

Comment: OLS = Ordinary Least Squares ? Please write "in extenso" the meaning of acronyms. Maybe you are working all the day in an environment where everybody knows what OLS means, but understand that even people that can help you here are not familiar with this abbreviation.

Comment: Perhaps you should start with an explicit statement of your AR (autoregressive?) model.

Comment: @JeanMarie I'll having some time to check details for my question and review previous questions in stackExchange. Thank you.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer Your page was helpful. Thank you